# Combine 2 Column s with the same name from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I Have 2 tables like shown below.

```
+----Table1-----+
+---------------------------+
| FirstName| LastName | ... |
+----+----------+-----------+
| Rick     | Grimes   | ... |
| Daryl    | Dixon    | ... |
```

And another table

```
+----Table2-----+
+---------------------------+
| FirstName| LastName | ... |
+----+----------+-----------+
| Norman   | Reedus   | ... |
```

I want a sql statement that will give me this output -

```
| LastName |
+-----------+
| Dixon   |
| Grimes  |
| Reedus  |
```

Managed to do it using union, but I want to achieve this result using JOIN. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the `union all` operator:

```
SELECT lastname
FROM   table1
UNION ALL
SELECT lastname
FROM   table2
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the fast reply. 
I just edited my query

Comment: @Optimize It would be very cumbersome to achieve what you want using a join, and a `UNION` is absolutely what you should be using here AFAIK.  Why do you think you need a join?

Comment: I just wanted to implement different soultion and wonder if it is possible to do using join. But I understand your reply. Thanks